# Type parameter in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand the type parameter concepts in scala.

```
def sum [A] (a:A):A={a}
// used single parameter and its working fine, able to pass any data type.
```

Here:

```
def sum[A](a:A,b:A):A={a+b} //declare two arguments

<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: String
 def sum[A](a:A,b:A):A={a+b}
```

The above function has a type parameter, I have not mentioned any data type - then how come it's treated as string?

Answer (score 4):

```
def sum[A](a:A,b:A):A={a+b}
```

You are adding `T` `+` `T`, the compiler can't infer the `+` for `T`, it will use the default `implicit +`: `any2stringadd`, so the compiler will throw `required: String` error.

see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8229

```
  implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
    def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at this from a little different perspective: what, actually, *is* a parameter? What does it mean?

And let's start with something you are probably more familiar with: *value parameters*. What does a value parameter in a subroutine mean? Say, we have something like this:

```
def foo(a, b) = { /* … */ } // deliberately ignoring types and the body
```

It means: I have a subroutine `foo` with two parameters, `a` and `b`. And the subroutine is *general*, it doesn't care what the *actual* concrete values of `a` and `b` are. It works for *all* values of `a` and `b` because it doesn't even *know* what the values of `a` and `b` are.

A little more concrete:

```
def plus(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```

Again, `plus` doesn't know what the actual values of `a` and `b` are. It works for `2` and `3` just as well as for `23` and `42` or `0` and `0`. It is completely and utterly ignorant of the concrete values of `a` and `b`. It only knows that `a` and `b` exist.

Now, *type parameters* are the same thing, just on the type level instead of the value level.

```
blabla[A]
```

means the same thing at the type level as `blabla(a)` means at the value level: "I have a thing, I have no idea what it is (and I don't care), but I'll call it `A`."

So, what you have effectively done, is to tell Scala that you don't know anything about `A`. But then you do something with it (or rather with its instance): you add it. But, how do you even know you *can* add it? You don't even know what it is!

So, adding it *cannot* possibly work, it *must* fail!

However, the *way* it fails is slightly strange, and has to do with some of the pre-defined [implicit conversions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#views) in the [`scala.Predef`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$) object. In particular, [there is an implicit conversion for string concatenation, which can convert an arbitrary object into a `String` and then concatenate another `String` to it](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$.html#any2stringadd[A]extendsAnyVal). In this case, it converts `a` to an [`any2stringadd`](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html) and then tries to add `b` to it, but the [`any2stringadd.+`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html#+(other:String):String) method only takes a `String` as its argument, and thus you get the strange error message that it is expecting a `String`.

[Note that `any2stringadd` is [*deprecated* in Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L375-L383), so in the future you would just get an error about a non-existent method.]

There are a couple of other similar types that sometimes pop up, when you have complex type errors:

- [`Any`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any), [`AnyRef`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef), [`AnyVal`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyVal): these types sit at the very top of Scala's type hierarchy. Sometimes, when you have some programming error, where you think you are returning the same type from two different code paths, but you actually return two different types, Scala will nonetheless try to infer the common type between the two, and end up with the only common ancestor being `Any`, `AnyRef`, or `AnyVal`. (That would be kind of like `Object` in Java or C♯.)
- [`Serializable`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Serializable): this is actually the same thing as above. Lots of completely different types implement the `Serializable` interface, so sometimes when you have two very different types where you actually expect the same type, Scala will helpfully infer `Serializable` as the closest common ancestor, and then yell at you for doing stuff with a `Serializable` that it doesn't support.
- [`Product`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product) is a super-trait of all `Product`s (i.e. [`Product1`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product1), [`Product2`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product2), … [`Product22`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Product22)) and thus all `Tuple`s (i.e. [`Tuple1`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple1), [`Tuple2`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple2), … [`Tuple22`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple22)). `Product` is also mixed into all `case class`es. So, if you have two `Tuple`s of different arity or two unrelated `case class`es (e.g. you sometimes return [`None`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.None$) but then accidentally return `somethingOfTypeFoo` instead of [`Some(somethingOfTypeFoo)`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Some)), then the most precise common type between [`Option`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option) and your `case class Foo` will be deduced as `Product` or …
- `Product with Serializable`: it is also possible to receive a combination of the above. E.g. `Tuple`s are `Serializable`, so *this* is actually the most precise common type of two `Tuple`s of different arity.

One common way to run into these problems is in a conditional expression without `else`:

```
if (true) 42
```

what type does this return? [`Int`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int)? No! The `then` branch returns `Int`, but the `else` branch returns *nothing* (because there is no `else` branch). Scala actually has a return type for not returning anything: [`Unit`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit). `Unit` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, `Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, so the closest common ancestor of the types of the two branches of the conditional expression is actually `AnyVal`, not `Int`. (Note: the fact that the `else` branch is unreachable is irrelevant from a typing perspective. Reachability is a runtime thing, types are a compile time thing.)