# How to cast or access element in an Array[Product with Serializable]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am loading  company records into spark

```
case class Company(id:Integer, name:String, kind: String, location : String, stage:String)
```

It is a large data file so i want to figure out which company records load correctly

```
safe: [S, T](f: S => T)S => Either[T,(S, Exception)]
```

loading the data with

```
val companiesText = sc.textFile("../companies.txt");
val safeParse = safe(parse)
val companyRecords = companiesText.map(line => line.split(";")).map(line => safeParse(line))
```

Access the company records that were correctly load

```
val goodCompaniesRecords = companyRecords.collect({
   case t if t.isLeft => t.left.get
 })
```

This gives an Array[Product with Serializable]  and i can not access the elements

```
goodCompaniesRecords.map(x => new Company(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5))
```

gives

```
error: value _1 is not a member of Product with Serializable
goodCompaniesRecords.map(x => new Company(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5))
```

How can i access these element or how can i cast from an Array[Product with Serializable] to Array[Company] without modifying the safe function?

Comment: `safe` should return a `Either[Company,(S, Exception)]` - why have the left-side type parameterized?

Answer (score 5):

Appearance of `Product with Serializable` basically always means you have an earlier problem, so a better question would be "how to avoid getting `Array[Product with Serializable]`". Specifically, it means you probably have an expression returning unrelated case classes in different branches somewhere (e.g. `None` and a `Company` instead of `Some(company)`, or tuples or different sizes). My guess (but only a guess, since you don't give enough code) is that this happens in `parse`.

To localize the problem, you can start giving explicit types to used variables and methods and checking if they still compile. In this case you should probably have `def parse(s: String): Company` and `val companyRecords: RDD[Array[Either[Company, (String, Exception)]]`.

On a side note, the pattern-match in `goodCompaniesRecords` is much better written as `case Left(company) => company`.

Comment: Upvoted for "Appearance of Product with Serializable basically always means you have an earlier problem"

Comment: Likewise. I added it to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39295031/2988 Is there a canonical question in [tag:scala] on [so] about this? Should there be?