# Not able to understand a Scala code snippet with `mkString` on `Array[Any]`

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming

I am a beginner exploring scala.The following is a Scala function.

```
def printArray[K](array:Array[K]) = array.mkString("Array(" , ", " , ")") 

val array2 = Array("a", 2, true)  
printArray(array2)
```

The output is 
Array(a, 2, true)

**My doubts**
Here we have given the array type as K. What does K means? Does it mean all types?
How is the fucntion 'mkString' able to give the output as Array(a, 2, true).
Basically I don't understand the concatenation part.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mkString` method called as

```
arr.mkString(prefix, separator, suffix)
```

will invoke `toString` on all array elements, prepend the `prefix`, then concatenate all strings separating them by the `separator`, and finally append the `suffix`.

The type parameter `K` in `printArray[K]` is ignored, it could be replaced by an existential. It's just a method with a bad name and confusing signature.

When you store any primitive data types (like `Int`) together with types that extend `AnyRef` (like `String`) into the same array, the least upper bound is inferred to be `Any`, so in

```
printArray(array2)
```

the `K` is set to `Any`, and the `mkString` works as described above, gluing together

```
Array(          prefix
a               "a".toString
,               separator
2               2.toString
,               separator
true            true.toString
)               suffix
```

yielding the string `Array(a,2,true)`.

Answer (score 3):

`K` is not a type here it is a type parameter, for more intuition have a look at other question [Type parameter in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283549/type-parameter-in-scala)

---

In this specific example `K` is infered to by `Any` - the most specific type that satisfies all 3 values `"a"`, `2` and `true`

```
val array2: Array[Any] = Array("a", 2, true)
```

---

the `mkString` function joins all items of collection into single string. It adds separator between items and some strings in the beginning and end. Documentation [mkString](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#mkString(start:String,sep:String,end:String):String)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `array2` definition in *REPL*, you will see that *array2 is of type Any*, *the parent type of all the other types in Scala*

```
scala> val array2 = Array("a", 2, true)
//array2: Array[Any] = Array(a, 2, true)
```

So when you call the function `def printArray[K](array:Array[K]) = array.mkString("Array(" , ", " , ")")` `K` now is treated as `Any` which returns a string with *intitial String* as `Array(` and *ending string* as `)` and *all the values separated* by `,`.

> > `def mkString(start: String, sep: String, end: String): String =
> >     addString(new StringBuilder(), start, sep, end).toString`